# Play Framework 2 cannot properly validate Json Arrays (code inside)

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to upload a JSON array of entities using Play.

My model looks like this:

```
case class Pet(name: String, age: Int)
object Pet {  
    implicit val petReads: Reads[Pet] = (
    (JsPath \ "name").read[String](minLength[String](2)) and
    (JsPath \ "age").read[Int](min(0))
    )(Pet.apply _)
)
```

My JSON input is a JSON array of entries. For example:

```
'[{"name": "Scooby","age":7},{"name": "Toothless","age": 3}]'
```

The action for working on the entries is this:

```
def create = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { implicit request =>
   val entries = request.body.validate[Seq[Pet]]
   entries.fold(errors => {BadRequest(Json.obj("status" -> "Bad Request",     "message" -> JsError.toJson(errors)))},
   elements => {//do something with it
   Ok(Json.obj("status" -> "OK", "message" -> (Json.toJson("Done."))))})
}
```

I want my validation to be able to detect value problems. For example, if the `string.length < 2` or the `age` number is negative.

However it doesn't work for arrays with `.validate[Seq[Pet]]`. Entries with a name of `length < 2` can get past the validation.

If I try to upload each entry individually as a simple JSON entry (not a json array) and use `.validate[Pet]` instead, everything works fine. Any tips on how to tweak the validation so that it works for arrays?

Comment: How about using: https://github.com/eclipsesource/play-json-schema-validator?

Comment: If `validate` works on a single entry, and `entries` is an array of such entries, why not `forEach` or `map` `validate` across `entries`? `request.body.map(x => x.validate[Seq[Pet]]` or something like that? (Caveat: I don't know the particular methods in question so I don't know how to precisely do this.)

Comment: Yes, I thought about them however none of the iteration functions of scala can be used on `request.body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, just use .validate[Array[Pet]] and it works out of the box.